# finding linked files with HPricot

Tags: ruby, hpricot

I've been playing around with HPricot, but after a fair amount of searching, I've not been able to work this out.

I'm trying to parse a HTML page and find all  tags with a href to an mp3 file. So far I've got

```
<ul>
    <% @page.search('//a[@href*=mp3]').each do |link| %>    
        <li>
            <%= link.inner_text %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

which is working fine, and a regex, `/href\s*=\s*\"([^\"]+)(.mp3)/` which also works. I'm just not sure how to combine the two.

Is there a good example, or documentation that someone could point me to in order to work out what I can do with the .search function.

Thanks

Comment: I've been able to file all links to mp3 files with <% @page.search('//a[@href*=.mp3]').each do |link| %>, but I'm still not sure how to isolate the href within that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer. the method is attributes, (not attr) and also, the brackets need to be square.  `link.attributes['href']`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the attribute `href` with

> <strike>link.attr('href')</strike>

As CSS3 selector you might want to consider `@href$=.mp3` (instead of `*=`) as it matches only attributes which *ends* in `.mp3`.

**Edit:**
You're right, sorry. I found out, that `attr` is only an alias for `set` for `Hpricot::Elements`. The right way is indeed:

```
link.attributes['href']
```

Nevertheless I would like to recommend Nokogiri as a [faster substitute](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-xml-performance-benchmarks-1641.html) for Hpricot.

Comment: thanks andre-r, I'm getting the error undefined method `attr' when I use that method. I've included both the HPricot and open-uri gems. Is there something I'm missing?